# Setting up a polynomial that has what I am referring to as a "wiggle root" at $x=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots

EDIT: I am loathe to delete/restructure this post, so I will include the following: A function has a "wiggle root" at $c$ if $f(c)=0$ and $f(x)$ crosses the $x$-axis.

I am trying to set up a polynomial such that it has a wiggle root at $x=0$. I have gotten it such that there are wiggle roots at $x=-1$ and $x=1$. A wiggle root is defined as the behavior of what you see at $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ in the image below. I do not know how to describe it conceptually other than the derivative at that point is such that it approaches from the positive $y$-axis from the left and negative $y$-axis from the right.

[image]

> My questions are:
>
> 1. What part of the polynomial determines whether the root is a wiggle root or not?
> 2. How do I create a polynomial that has a wiggle root and also satisfies these conditions: the polynomial should have 2 imaginary roots, 2 real roots, and double roots. It should be fully factorable.

Here are some other polynomials that I have tried:

$$P(x) = (x+1)(x+1)(x-1)(x-1)(x+i)(x-i)$$
or
$$P(x) = x^6+2x^5+x^4−x^2−2x−1$$

Comment: What's a “wiggle root”?

Comment: I have updated the question to show the wiggle root, as I do not know how to describe it conceptually other than the derivative at that point is 0 such that it approaches from the positive y axis from the left and negative y axis from the right

Comment: That behavior happens when the multiplicity of the root is odd and greater than 1.

Comment: @Shanty But only one of the roots in the picture "approaches from the positive y axix from the left and the negative y axis from the right."

Comment: Those two polynomials, $P(x)$ are not the same.  The first one has constant term $+1$, for example.  The second one has $(x+1)^3$ as a factor.

Comment: Does the polynomial $-x^3$ have a wiggle root at $0$?

Comment: Please **prepare your question more carefully** before you ask it.  Your two expressions for $P(x)$ are not the same, and neither of them has the graph you have shown.  This is just wasting people's time.

Comment: @bof yes. -x cubed has a wiggle root at 0. As for the approaches from the positive y axis from the left and the negative y axis from the right." part, it can be vice versa also

Comment: $-1$. I think OP should respond to David's comment.

Comment: @David  I have edited the question a bit to address some of these comments. I have kept his terminology of "wiggle root" despite it not being standard!

Comment: I really think we need to edit the question to establish the desire for a derivative of 0 and a crossing (i.e., odd multiplicity greater than 1), without having to read the comments for that info.

Comment: I have included a definition of the term "wiggle root" as per the criterion discussed in the commments

Answer (score 1):

What you describe as a "wiggle root" is a stationary point of inflection of the curve $y=f(x)$ that is also a root of the equation $f(x)=0$.

You therefore require:

1) $f(a)=0$ : to make $a$ a root of the equation

2) $f'(a)=0$ : to make $(a,0)$ a stationary point of the curve

3) $f''(a)=0$ : to make $(a,0)$ a point of inflection

```
      As egreg noted in a comment this last condition is
      necessary but not sufficient. The polynomial must
      have the factor (x-a) raised to an odd power greater
      than or equal to 3 to fully achieve a "wiggle root".
```

You have tried to set up your polynomial as $f(x)=(x-a)^2(x-b)^2(x-ci)(x+ci)$, but this will not have stationary points of inflection at $x=a$ and $x=b$. To achieve that you will need something like:

$$f(x)=(x-a)^3(x-b)^3(x-ci)(x+ci)$$

To have a stationary point of inflection at $x=0$ you will have to include the factor $x^3$, giving you:

$$f(x)=x^3(x-a)^3(x-b)^3(x-ci)(x+ci)$$

I wasn't sure if you wanted there to be two real roots and a third root at $x=0$, but if you just want two real roots (one of which is $x=0$), then you want:

$$f(x)=x^3(x-a)^3(x-ci)(x+ci)$$

Comment: The order of the zero should also be odd: the polynomial $x^4$ satisfies conditions 1–3 at $0$, but $0$ is not an inflection point. In particular, if the number of roots is odd and all of them must be “wiggle”, then the degree of the polynomial is odd.

Answer (score 1):

Definition: A polynomial, $f(x)$, has a "wiggle root" at $a$ if and only if $f(a)=0$ and the degree of the root is an odd number greater than $1$.

Claim: If you are interested in finding polynomials that have wiggle roots at $a$, you just have to look at $(x-a)^3(x-a)^{2k}p(x)$. As $p(x)$ ranges over all polynomials that are not zero at $a$, this will actually give you every polynomial with a wiggle root at $a$.

Proof of the above claim:

1) It's clear that this form always has a wiggle root by the definition I described.

2) Let $p(x)$ have a wiggle root at $a$. Then $\exists$ a maximum $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(x-a)^{2k+1}|p(x)$ and so $p(x)=q(x)(x-a)^{2k+1}$. Then we also have that $p(x)=q(x)(x-a)^3(x-a)^{2(k-1)}$ and so we are done, since $k$ being maximum implies that $(x-a)\not|q(x)$